# Can't deploy a simple java restfull api on heroku

Tags: java, rest, maven, heroku

I have had it. All day I have been busy trying to deploy a very simple rest application with jersey and spring. First on openshift, which just gave me an error that actually told me nothing, no reason, no exception, just chaos in a red box.

So I went to heroku. I like it more, because it gives me the feeling you can do more... however, after a 8 hours, I haven't had any success.

I tried everything: the java get started, adding buildpacks heroku/java, adding all different kind of files (Procfile, Procfilew.windows, system.properties), then i tried the webapp-runner, adding that plugin which is suggested [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner) . That was the most succesful road so far, as I could start my application locally with that webapp-runner (hooray, that actually went smoothly).

However, no matter what i try, I always get the same error when I do git push heroku master, which is:

```
Counting objects: 109, done.Delta compression using up to 6 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
Writing objects: 100% (109/109), 13.33 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 109 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:       to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to facetdata.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/facetdata.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/facetdata.git'
```

I have added an app.json file (i saw one of those in the java get started application ) but to no avail. I have added and set buildpacks, to no avail.

I am frustrated as hell, as I strongly believe that this shouldn't all be that complex.

This is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>be.facet-it.rest.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>DataApi</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DataApi</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>DataApi</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.24.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springversion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springversion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springversion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <properties>
        <jersey.version>1.19</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <springversion>4.2.4.RELEASE</springversion>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>Tomcat</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>
</project>
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:context/data-api-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>        
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>be.facetit.rest.data.dataapi</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

as you can see, quite simple. The application works when i deploy it on a local tomcat, it also runs locally using the webapp-runner. What am i not seeing in order to get it deployed on heroku?

thanks!

Comment: And now i wonder: why does it get downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

```
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:       to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
```

Means Heroku can't find your `pom.xml`. It needs to be checked into Git (you can confirm with `git ls-files` and it needs to be in the root directory (the top level Git dir).

Comment: Hmm, thank you for your comment. I believe my project structure in git is wrong. I ll fix that first. tnx and I ll let you know about the result

Comment: So I changed the structure. Although my pom file was where it is supposed to be, the project itself was put in a subfolder. I emptied the git folder and put a copy of the project on the git root folder. So thanks a lot to clarify that for me! I just wonder why the error just couldn't say: Can't find the pom, instead of the buildpack hint.

Comment: Heroku supports lots of different kinds of apps (Node.js, Ruby, Python, PHP, etc). Without a pom.xml, the auto-detection has no way of know if your app even needs a pom.xml or if its a Java project. If you wanted to bypass the auto-detection you could explicitly set the buildpack by running `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/java`, then you would get a more specific message.

Comment: Setting the buildpacks to heroku/java was one of the first things I did. That was actually the most frustrating part, reading again and again that heroku cannot find the buildpack, while i had just finished setting it. Anyway, your help is very much appreciated!